# How do I dismiss many multiples of the "Disk Not Ejected Properly" notification in macOS?

Tags: macos, external-disk, error, eject

Today I'm dealing with the following problem:

[image: Never Ending Eject Notifications]

Is there some way I can get rid of these without spending my entire day clicking, short of Homer's Drinking Bird?

[image]

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of [How do I clear All OS X notifications with 1 click?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/184633/37037), because the notifications in my question aren't shown at all in the Notification Center, and thus the solution in that question doesn't work for this question.

Comment: I edited this question to explain how it's different from the one marked as a duplicate - the main distinction being that the linked solution doesn't actually work in this case.

Comment: Did you work out what causes this?  I have a new USB hub, with backup disk attached to it, and I'm getting this...

Comment: This is still happening in 2024... I submitted a bug report for macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. I woke up to the new year with hundreds of those. If you disable the auto sleep for hard disks, you don't get those. But what if I want the internal hard disk to sleep? macOS was the one "ejecting" the external hard disk, not me... Thanks for the "killall NotificationCenter". It saved me hundreds of clicks!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I started killing processes with "Notification" in their name, and when I hit the one called "NotificationCenter" the smoke finally cleared:

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

Comment: Ken, you made my weekend - I'm going to name a puppy after you! I might sound silly yelling "Ken Williams!" all over the park, but I'm good with that

Comment: FWIW, `pkill NotificationCenter` works pretty much the same way. And it seems good to restart the process afterwards--its at: `/System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app/Contents/MacOS/NotificationCenter &` (There's probably a more sophisticated way to do this with a single restart signal.)

Comment: @MarkHu: More gracefully: `open /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app`

Comment: maybe its the new OS update, but they come back a second later, like a bunch of zombies

Comment: This is by far the best answer .. and the answer I was looking for.  I had already tried "killall Dock" and "killall Finder", but those did not clear the notifications.    I wish there was a cleaner way to do this, but this works, and currently does not leave zombie processes behind (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 7):

The Apple Script from "software is fun", with 3 votes at the time of writing, in the [suggested duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184633/how-do-i-clear-all-os-x-notifications-with-1-click) gets rid of all "Disk Not Ejected Properly" notifications on High Sierra (additionally you have to allow 
Script Editor to control the computer in Accessibility preferences as the post suggests):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NotificationCenter"
        set numwins to (count windows)
        repeat with i from numwins to 1 by -1
            click button "Close" of window i
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I have the same problem and am not familiar with utilizing scripts on my Mac. Can anyone walk me through this process. I can't keep pressing the close button its killing me.

Comment: This works great with Keyboard Maestro. Have it run the script when a usb drive is disconnected.

Comment: @user303817 the linked question has a demonstration of how to run a script like this.

Comment: yessss, I did this using hammerspoon instead of Keyboard Maestro. thanks!