# How to disable alerts but not banners in mac os x notification center as a global setting?

Tags: macos, notifications, folders, system-settings, alert

There are 2 types of notifications, *alerts* and *banners* . *Banners* go away on their own, whereas you have to interact/click  *alerts* to make them go away. In the System preferences>Notifications, there are some apps for which you can set the notification style as *banners*. But all apps are not shown in System preferences/Notifications. e.g. this image. The system shows you *alerts* which you have to interact/click. I do not want to do that. I want the notifications to show and go on their own with no interaction on my part. Is there any way to permanently make the system/mac os show only *banners* and **not alerts**. Kindly tell me which system file I have to modify and how to modify it. Because as I understand Apple is not going to implement a global setting to set all notifications as banners (why? because they are attention suckers and irritate in a subtle kind of way folks). Any help would be appreciated.[image: alerts that don't go away without interaction]

Comment: More specifically, I want the notifications (alerts or banners) to behave exactly the same way, to show the text of notification and stay for 1 or 2 seconds and go away on their own without any user input. I want the notifications to not show on the desktop upper right hand corner after 1 or 2 seconds, but to remain in the notifications panel. Subpart 2: And if possible, completely disable "disk not ejected properly" alerts.

Comment: My goal remains the same (making all notifications alerts or banners to disappear after 2 to 3 seconds). However I have not found a solution.

Comment: For the most irritating “Disk not ejected properly” alerts, some answers to some questions asked by others are helpful, like these ones [a](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310971/396295) , [b](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325636/396295), [c](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/241791/396295). These solutions suggested using applescript. But for these solutions to work I have to invoke/start the script. I wanted the script to run all the time(check for "disk not ejected properly" error message, remain idle for 60 seconds, recheck) and quitable when quit.

Comment: For that I needed to put idle handler and quit handler, which I tried to do, looking at applescript Q&A. But the handlers do not work as expected. idle handler (do not recheck every 60 seconds), quit handler (do not quit or quit after long time). Here are the scripts with which I tried to achieve the end result of this "disk not ejected properly" error message disappearing.

Comment: `on run
tell application "System Events"
tell process "NotificationCenter"
set numwins to (count windows)
repeat with i from numwins to 1 by -1
tell window i
set temp to value of static text 1
end tell
if temp contains "Disk Not Ejected Properly" then
click button "Close" of window i
end if
end repeat
end tell
end tell
end run

on idle
delay 60
end idle

on quit
continue quit
end quit`

Comment: Kindly kindly help