# Programmatic (AppleScript) access to notification centre history

Tags: applescript, notifications

I have followed this thread, which addresses active notifications which appear on the desktop: [How do I clear All OS X notifications with 1 click?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184633/how-do-i-clear-all-os-x-notifications-with-1-click). These solutions offer programatic approaches to clear all active desktop notifications from the notification centre. Are there similar AppleScript hooks to clear the notification centre history within the notification centre itself?