# How to paste today's date *and initials* with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard

This question will be asked and answered, thanks to the contributors to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242547/how-to-automatically-paste-todays-date-with-keyboard-shortcut) previous question.

I am on High Sierra OS X.

I want to be able to hit some keyboard shortcut and then have today's date ***and my initials*** inserted into text. This will be a date stamp used when making entries into a CRM database.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the Service created to put your date stamp and initials into any document.
The first line returns today's date.
The second line is the text to include after the date.
The third line appends the date and text together.

Following the [directions in the previous thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242547/how-to-automatically-paste-todays-date-with-keyboard-shortcut), create the Service and assign a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services. (In System Preferences, Services are organized by type. The new Service you created will appear under the "Text" group of services.)

Note that your new Service will not appear in the Services menu unless the cursor is inserted into a field as if you were about to type the date and initials manually.

The output of this shortcut is circled in red below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use Typinator for all kinds of neat shortcuts. It works well.