# Keyboard Shortcut for Automator Service

Tags: keyboard, catalina, automator, shortcut, services

I have a word count 'services' called with LMB and scrolling down to the services menu. I'd like to have a keyboard shortcut for it since I use it very often. All of the answers I see require that the services be in finder, but that doesn't seem to work with word count needing to extract from the current application. Under 'services' in keyboard shortcuts, is there's no way to select the 'services' that are in LMB? I'm in Catalina.

[image][image]

I've looked at the answers here [Keyboard shortcut (almost) never works for Automator service](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360128/keyboard-shortcut-almost-never-works-for-automator-service?noredirect=1&lq=1) and am still unable to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I'd just use the free WordService app from https://www.devontechnologies.com/support/download as it does so much more than the home spun one. (I am not affiliated with the developer, just a satisfied user.)

Comment: Do you count words under multiple apps? You could create several services for every application and use the same shortcut.

Comment: Also make sure the apps are enabled to control your computer in privacy settings.
https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchl07817563/mac