# Assign command up (⌘↑) to go to parent folder in iTerm

Tags: shortcut, iterm

The <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> key takes you to the parent folder in Finder.

How can I assign this key to do the same in iTerm - basically an alias for `cd ..`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with keyboard maestro:
Create a macro group for iterm.
[image]

Create the following macro.
[image]

Place the macro in the iterm group.

Answer (score 1):

Applescript syntax for iterm:
https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html#documentation-scripting.html
How to call your applescript with a keyboard shortcut:
[How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to an AppleScript I wrote?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote)