# Open farthest right tab in Safari

Tags: safari, tabs

In Chrome, one can press `cmd+1` to open the first tab, `cmd+3` to open the third tab, etc...  Safari has replicated this behavior now but has not replicated `cmd+9` which takes the user to the far right tab even if there are dozens of tabs in the window.  Is there a way to map `cmd+9` or another key mapping to that action?

Answer (score 1):

That was a fun question to tackle! Follow the instructions below and paste this code in step 1.8:

```
set n to 0

tell application "Safari"
    repeat with w in windows
        try
            set n to n + (count tabs of w)
        end try
    end repeat
end tell



tell front window of application "Safari"
    set current tab to tab n
end tell
```

This will tell Safari to change to the right most tab. Then, to map it to a key shortcut, just follow the steps listed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote) by `Monomeeth` which is shown below. The code was adapted from [here](https://gist.github.com/jjeising/a31c8ddd33479a7b6b87)

In summary you will need to use:

- Automator to create a service that runs an Apple Script
- System Preferences to assign a keyboard shortcut to the service

Below are the steps involved for each.

**1. Create a service using Automator**

1. Launch Automator (usually found within your Applications folder)
2. Go to File > New
3. Select Service and click Choose
4. In the top right hand of the window that appears, ensure that "No input" is selected from the *Service receives* drop-down list
5. Ensure the *In* drop-down list is showing "Any application"
6. In the second column containing the long list, find "Run AppleScript" and double-click on it
7. This will add the Run AppleScript window on the right
8. Now, **replace** the (* Your script goes here *) with the script you want (the one I provided above)
9. Save the service using a meaningful name (e.g. RightMostTab).

Now to the next step.

**2. Creating your shortcut**

1. Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
2. Select Services from the sidebar
3. Find your service (it'll be in the list on the right-hand side)
4. Add a shortcut by double clicking on the service name
5. Now go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy
6. Select *Accessibility* in the sidebar
7. Click on the + sign (you may need to unlock the padlock if it's locked)
8. Add Automator.
9. Add Finder (to find this you will need to navigate to */System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app*).
10. Exit your System Preferences.

Let me know how it goes!