# Is there a shortcut to "Switch User" from the Lock Screen in macOS Mojave?

Tags: mojave, fast-user-switching, lockscreen

Let's say you lock your screen with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd>. Now, you want to log in as a different user, without using the mouse.

It seems that this is possible if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>Space</kbd>. (Essentially, it brings the focus to the "Switch User" button, and then pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> selects it.

I am wondering if there is some less cumbersome keyboard shortcut to do the same thing?

---

Alternatively, is there a keyboard shortcut to Fast User Switch when already logged in? (I have searched for this and only found older articles, suggesting the use of 3rd party software).

Answer (score 0):

There might not be a ready made one - but you can write your own!

[This link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote) explains how to apply a shortcut to some applescript that you have already written.

If you are not familiar with Applescript (new skill to learn! :)), you could check out [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/44433/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-fast-user-switching-in-mac-os-x) where there are a number of other suggestions (including a user switch script - but your password will be in plain text).

Let us know which one works for you.

Comment: Is this possible from the Lock Screen?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a note to add a reference to [On lock screen, how to select 'other user' with keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451448/on-lock-screen-how-to-select-other-user-with-keyboard)

As your method "press Shift Tab twice, followed by Tab and then Space. (Essentially, it brings the focus to the "Switch User" button, and then pressing Space selects it.)" Doesn't work for me, **unless** I first put a character in the password field, as mentioned in that answer.