# On lock screen, how to select 'other user' with keyboard?

Tags: macos, keybindings

We share a imac with 4 people. Most of the time the computer switches on it is locked for someone else. I'd like to switch to my own account without using a mouse.

From the lock screen, how do I select the 'Other user' button using the keyboard? (The 'Other user' button opens the 'list of users' screen.)

Keys I have tried:

- [Tab] The cursor disappears from the password widget, but the 'Cancel' and 'Other user' buttons do not seem to be activated. (After pressing [Tab], [Enter] tries to submit the entered password, [space] is seen as a password character.)
- [Up], [Down], [Left], [Right], don't seem to do anything.

Comment: Turn off the icon-based user selection, it will switch to asking for a username and a password.

Comment: Nice work around @MarcWilson ! Unfortunately, my family will never accept that.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the MacOS details.

Comment: @FrederikKrautwald I did not include that because it has been like this for all MacOS version in the last ~10 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, type a character in the password field. Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times until the Switch User icon is highlighted. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>. You can now select users by typing the first character of their names. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select.

You must type a character in the password field before this works.

Comment: First typing some characters did the trick. Thanks Frederik!

Answer (score 0):

Oops - sorry! I pictured your screen incorrectly, so my answer here, while correct for what it says, doesn't answer your question - e.g., when there is only a password field available, not a list of users. If I find a useful solution, I'll update.

When the login screen shows multiple users, including "other user", just type the first letter of the username you want to log in as ("o" for "other user". You'll see a border appear around the username; hit return and you'll get the password field. (Monterey 12.6.2, old Mac Mini)

Answer (score 0):

Press `0` on Numpad, then use the arrow keys

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. This enters a character in the password field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is two stage process: (1) Activate navigation (2) Navigate

To activate navigation press simultaneously <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> (control+option+shift+down arrow)

To navigate use <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> (right and left arrow).

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work for me though. After pressing the key-combo, focus stays on the password field.

Comment: In order to loose focus on password field press ESC

Comment: Nope, pressing Esc will turn the screen off.

Comment: I couldn't replicate this. Probably there is something somewhere in Systems Settings  which makes behavior different (Lock Screen? Battery? Keyboard shortcuts? Language & Regional settings?). For example my Lock Screen is "List of users"

Comment: Quote: "For example my Lock Screen is 'List of users'.".
That is very different from what I see. When I turn on my computer, I get a password prompt for the last active user. My goal is to open the 'list of users' screen from there!