# How to add a Service to Accessibility permissions

Tags: applescript, automator, accessibility

I have a Quick Action which I wrote in Automator (it runs an AppleScript). It is launching from a keyboard shortcut correctly ([using this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote/276839)).

However, when I try to give it permissions in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility, it won't allow me to select the workflow file (it's grey'd out).

Is there any way to achieve this?

- Launch an AppleScript from a keyboard shortcut
- AND allow it to send keystrokes (so give it Accessibility permissions)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the roundabout way I achieved it.

1. In Automator write your application, and save it as an Application (`foo.app`)
2. In Automator, create a separate Quick Action. Get that Quick Action to launch the previous Application you created (`launchfoo.workflow`)
3. System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility: Add `foo.app` to the permissions
4. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services: Give `launchfoo` a shortcut