# Use [command]-[return] for shortcut

Tags: terminal, keyboard, applescript, keybindings

**My Problem**

On my Mac I would love to emulate my Linux development workflow using key-binds. A core part of this workflow is that when I press `[super]-[enter]` a new terminal window opens.

**My Attempts**

I have an `automator` service that opens a new terminal for me, whether or not my iterm2 application is running.  I am trying to assign that service to a shortcut [using instructions found here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote).  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to assign it the shortcut that I would prefer, which is `[command]-[return]`.  Am I missing something? Is this just not supported, or is there a workaround that I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, one cannot assign **⌘↩** in:

**System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

However, one can assign **⌘↩** in [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).

---

<sub>Note that I am not affiliated with the developer of FastScripts, just a satisfied user of the product.</sub>

Comment: Gets the job done for me, thanks!  I didn't find a "getting started guide" for FastScripts, so I had to dig a little bit.  For documentation's sake, what worked for me was to create the script: `/Library/Scripts/<newdirectory>/<newfile>.applescript` then go open `FastScripts -> Preferences` and select the file to create the shortcut.

Comment: @Brett Holman, Yeah documentation is sparse. There is [FastScripts: Frequently Asked Questions](https://help.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/faq/), which may be helpful.

Comment: @CJK, Pressing **fn** in conjunction with **⌘↩** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** did not allow **⌘↩** to be assigned for me in **macOS High Sierra**. Also, I have in the past tried editing the `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` file to add **⌘↩** for a _service_ and it did not work. YMMV This is one of the reasons I use FastScripts.

Comment: Ah well, I knew it wasn't guaranteed, although I've had some good instances with both techniques where I got what I wanted.  But, I'm certainly not arguing against the merits of _`FastScripts`_, of which I am a faithful user and my life would definitely be worse without it.