# osascript gets "System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-1728)"

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a modest (~250 lines) python3 script using tkinter and subprocesses.
The python script launches a macOS app using the "run" subprocess.

Python defined functions then query the system for information on the spawned app.

Everything works fine when I run the Python code directly from the shell, from within BBEdit, or within PyCharm but fails if I build it into an app using either Platypus or Automator.

I've added osascript, Platypus, Automator, System Events, and the built app to the "Accessibility" settings pane (in Privacy & Security)and tried several logout/ins and restarts.

No Joy!

Comment: I have no idea if this would work [nor why it worked for me] - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411652/85275

Comment: Error -1728 is `errAENoSuchObject`, so it may not necessarily be a permissions issue.  Note that `osascript` inherits its environment from the shell it is run from.

Comment: The script runs fine when launched in zsh or bash. When I use Automator to build an app I only use the 'run shell' thing from the library and specify my script as the target,; that does not run (same error).

Comment: Automator's **Run Shell Script** and AppleScript's `do shell script` do not read any configuration files, so $PATH will not reflect any of your changes - you will need to set up the shell environment or use full paths.  In addition, a current working directory is not set, so that would also need to be set for anything that expects one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved or at least, identified.

I had chosen a space separated, two word name for the app I was trying to build. I was testing the generated app which  produced the problem.

Oh a hunch I replaced the space with an underscore and the Automator produced app ran, after prompting for the necessary permissions. Sadly, the Platypus generated app still won't run.

I say sadly because the Platypus generated app is less than 1/3 the size of the Automator one.

In any event, thanks to all who offered hints, clues, and assistance.