# Keyboard shortcut to call an AppleScript (created with Automator --> Quick Action) always require app permission

Tags: applescript, keybindings

I've followed [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/276839/428538) in order to add [this AppleScript](https://github.com/randy3k/osascript/blob/master/Move%20Window%20Down.applescript) to a keyboard shortcut. It works but it doesn't resize the window, and I receive the [following message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuEWX.jpg):

> com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed assistive access

I've already added `Automator` to the list of applications with full control in `Privacy & Security --> Accessibility`.

I found out that if I add the application i'm trying to resize to the list it works.

Is there any workaround? Or the OS doesn't allow this?

I don't want to add applications to the `Privacy & Security --> Accessibility` list just to be able to resize them.

Comment: Have you already tried this suggestion, to turn the AppleScript into an Application? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349831/com-automator-runner-xpc-is-not-allowed-assistive-access-cannot-click-when-run

Comment: @ChrisNorman it *kinda* works by following that procedure to turn it into a service by editing the `info.plist`. The annoying thing is that everytime I use the shortcut it asks for a [service confirmation](https://imgur.com/a/TbtwZDB)